# USB audio on 12.04 LTS

Tags: sound

I have a Schiit Audio USB DAC. In the 'Sound' section of System Settings, I can see the device, but when I push the Test button, it doesn't work. If I run 'gstreamer-properties' from Terminal, and test there with ALSA, it works-but I can't get sound to work from System Settings or in any application.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggeling to get the DAC working also.
The solution was to add the user accessing the DAC to the audio group

Comment: Could you please elaborate on *how to add the user to the audio group* ?